# connect in qt using two different classes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to connect a signal and a slot from two different classes in which one is using the other like this example:

***form.hpp***

```
class Form : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form();
public slots:
     void onPushButton(void);    

};
```

***form.cpp***

```
Form::Form() :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(..., SIGNAL(clicked()),..., SLOT(onPushButton()));

}

void Form::onPushButton(void)
{
    ui->pushButton->setText(QString("clicked"));
}
```

***mainwindow.hpp***

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Form f;
};
```

***mainwindow.cpp***

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

I know it easy to solve but I don't know how to do it. What the syntax of `connect` in `Form::Form()`?
If it was the way around I would do it like that:

```
connect(&f, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(onPushButton()));
```

Comment: to make a connection you must be able to access the objects that you want to connect, in the Form constructor you can access `this` that represents the Form object but you can not access the MainWindow object so you can not connect there, in change in the MainWindow constructor you can access `this` that represents the MainWindow object and f which is the object of Form, in that part you can make the connection.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes you understand correctly my issue.. so you think it's not possible?

Comment: It is not possible as it is, if you want to do it you should look for some way to pass the MainWindow object to Form, but I do not see it right so I see that Every MainWindow has a Form, but not all Form belongs to a MainWindow, so that the connection must be made in the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: Why do you want to make the connection in the Form constructor ?, the proper thing as I repeat is in the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to get some text from a lineEdit widgets and send it to Form where I do some processing using that piece of information

Comment: When do you want the information to be sent, when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes the user will fill the lineEdit and press the button to be sent to the other class where it is used

Comment: the button belongs to MainWindow?

Comment: Yes all the widgets are belonging to MainWindow

Comment: Please [edit] your question with all those details (and more). It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Ja_cpp see my answer :)

Comment: Prefer using the "new" compile time checked pointer-to-member-function syntax for `connect`. Safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection must be made in the MainWindow constructor, but you must use a lambda method since the signal does not pass the text to it.

**form.h**

```
class Form : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form();
public slots:
     void processingFunction(const QString & text);    

};
```

**form.cpp**

```
Form::Form() :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

void Form::processingFunction(const QString & text)
{
    // some processing
}
```

---

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this](){
        f.processingFunction(ui->lineEdit->text());
    });
}
```

Comment: Right! The solution is to use connect in MainWindow.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**
Class `Form` is **not** emiting `clicked` signal. You should connect a `QPushButton` (or similar) instead the class `Form`. Otherwise you should declare signal `clicked()` in your class and `emit` it somewhere in your code:

```
class Form : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form();

signals:
    void clicked();

public slots:
     void onPushButton(void);
};

void Form::someFunction(/* parameters */)
{
    emit clicked();
}
```

Also, if you want to make the connection you mention at the end, you should do it in the `MainWindow` class, because you can't access `MainWindow` from `Form`, unless you make `MainWindow` the parent of `Form` and then call `parent()` function to access `MainWindow` through a pointer. But that is an insane and discouraged programming practice because `Form` must **not** know about the existence of `MainWindow`.

Although Qt4-style `connect()` (using `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros) is still supported in Qt5, it's deprecated and may be removed from Qt6 in 2019, so you must switch to Qt5-style `connect()`:

```
QObject::connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged,
                   label,  &QLabel::setText);
```

This has several pros:

- Errors can be raised at compilation-time, rather than execution time.
- C++11 Lambdas can be used.

See this:

```
connect(sender, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]() {
    // Code here. Do whatever you want.
});
```

- Are a lot faster to resolve.

Take a look at: [Qt5 Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't answer my question!